Confirming receipt of document in formal email
How do I express confirmation of a document recieved on email in a professional manner?
In English the phrase 'well recieved' is quite common if I translate this I was thinking something like 'gut Bekommen' but I am not sure if this a common or appropriate phrasing in professional German.
Help?

Do you want to acknowledge that the document has reached you technically, or is about your reaction to it? "Well received" sounds more like the latter, as in "The idea was well received by the higher-ups".

In this context well received means the document has arrived. It's not a comment on its contents. Your question prompted me to double check and yes normally well received would be used as a positive response to something. In my business experience it's a quick way to acknowledge receipt but I've never taken it to imply positive opinion. Maybe for clarity I would ask if there is a German way to communicate that I acknowledge reciept, in a short, professional way.

Interesting, I've never run across that phrase in English.

Yes, seems it has some controversy with some saying the addition of well implies acceptance. But in my experience this is a fairly common phrase used as a friendly but professional sounding confirmation. Other ways could be 'noted' but I avoid this since it often sounds cold.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536190/can-i-use-well-received-as-a-response-to-professional-emails I agree with the answer in that post. It most certainly carries that connotation in American English. It could be different in other places; Indian English sometimes uses expressions that sound a bit funny to speakers of other English varieties.

"Gut bekommen" refers more to how something does for a person, as in

Ich habe gestern fünf Stück Kuchen gegessen. Das ist mir nicht gut bekommen, jetzt habe ich Bauchweh.
I ate five pieces of pie yesterday. That didn't do me good, now I've got a stomach ache.

A more fitting synonyme for "bekommen" in a formal context would be "erhalten". So you could say:

Wir bestätigen, dass wir das Dokument erhalten haben.
We confirm that we received the document.

or, a little bit less formal

Ihr Dokument ist bei uns eingetroffen und wird zeitnah bearbeitet.
Your document has arrived with us and will be processed soon.


Oh interesting... So for a personalised answer it would be something like: 'ich bestätige dass ich habe das Dokument erhalten.'?

@tana Almost. In the sub clause, the word order is changed: "Ich bestätige, dass ich das Dokument erhalten habe."

Oder: "Ich bestätige das Dokument erhalten zu haben". Sehr informell: "Kam an./Ist angekommen./Danke." Insbesondere, wenn aus dem Email-Subject hervorgeht, worum es sich handelt.

In the communication I receive, the word "Eingangsbestätigung" or "Empfangsbestätigung" is often used. Quotes from some of my communication which I received after transmitting documents which contain an order - but these words could identically be used when sending any documents for whatever reason:

Subject: Eingangsbestätigung
Sehr geehrte(r) Frau/Herr XXX,
vielen Dank für Ihre Bestellung. Hiermit bestätigen wir den Eingang.
Ihre Bestellnummer lautet XXX und Ihre Bestellsumme beträgt YYYY €.
Ihre Daten wurden in unser System übertragen.
Der Auftrag wird erst verbindlich, wenn wir Ihre Bestellung schriftlich oder in anderer Textform innerhalb von 2 Wochen bestätigen oder Ihnen innerhalb von 2 Wochen die Ware zusenden.


(...) hiermit bestätigen wir den Eingang Ihrer Bestellung. (...)


(...)COMPANYNAME Empfangsbestätigung - Ihre Bestellung XXX wurde auf COMPANYNAME platziert. (...)

